# VB.net sendmessge to console box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, console, findwindow

Hey all, i am trying to send some text to a console box (dos box) from my vb program but i can not seem to get it working.

Here is my current code:

```
Dim blah As Long
Private Const WM_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr

blah = FindWindow1(vbNullString, "Form1")
blah = FindWindowEx(blah, vbNullString, "ConsoleWindowClass", vbNullString)
Debug.Print(blah)
SendMessage(blah, WM_SETTEXT, 200, "A")
```

Though that does work, it only puts a **A** for the title bar and not within the console.

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but I think you might want to look at [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952%28VS.85%29.aspx) to attach your process to the console of the command line process. Then you should be able to use the `Console.WriteLine` and similar methods I'd assume.

You can find a sample (in C#, but should be easy to convert to VB using one of the online converters) on the [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.attachconsole) page.

Comment: Unless he wants to interact with the program in the console.